# Change images with different timeinterval using Js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, css

How to change images with different time interval in a single div using CSS3, JavaScript or jQuery. At the last time interval should be cleared.

Comment: What have you done? Show your attempted code.

Also, remove the C# tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/PNErKp

```
var timing = [1000, 2000, 500, 300, 800],
  timeouts

function runinterval() {
  timeouts = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeouts);
    timing.shift();
    $(".imgholder").css("background-image", "url(https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random&i=" + new Date().getTime() + ")")
    if (timing.length != 0)
      runinterval();
  }, timing[0])
}
runinterval();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can help you.

```
var setTimer = (function(){

    function setTimer( options ){

        this.timings   = options.timings;
        this.element   = options.element;
        this.images    = options.images;
        this.index     = -1;
        this.interval  = false;
        this.init();

    }

    setTimer.prototype.init = function(){

        this.image_ = document.createElement('img');
        this.image_.setAttribute('class','slider-image');
        this.element.appendChild( this.image_ );
        this.set();

    };

    setTimer.prototype.set = function(){

        if( this.interval && false !== this.interval ){
            clearTimeout( this.interval );
        }

        if( this.index >= this.images.length-1 ){ this.index = 0; } 
        else{ this.index++; }


        var timing = this.timings[this.index];
        console.log(this.index);
        console.log(timing);

        this.interval = (function(_this){
                          return setTimeout(function(){

                             _this.switch_image();

                          },timing);
                         })(this);

    };


    setTimer.prototype.switch_image = function(){

       var index = this.index;
       console.log('switching image to '+this.images[index]);

       this.image_.setAttribute('src',this.images[index]);
       this.set();


    }

    return setTimer;

})();

setTimeout(function(){

var options = {
  timings: [10,1000,2000],
  images : [ 'url1','url2','url3'],
  element: document.getElementById('your-image-container-id')
};
new setTimer(options);

},1000);
```